# Ticket Booking Program

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

I am a beginner in Python, as you will see looking at my notes.
This is a program that simulates seat booking in a cinema for example.
The program stores the users name as a key and the seat(s) they have chosen in a dictionary as key-value
pairs.

What are the ways I can improve this program? I have used one function. Would defining more functions make my program cleaner and more concise.
Please don't comments too hard, I'm working on making them more concise.

```
# Ticket Booking System.
def print_tickets():
    """Print the tickets of the user."""
    for user_name, seats in user_tickets.items():
        print(f"\nYou, {user_name.title()}, have chosen {len(seats)} seat(s).")
        for seat in seats:
            print(f"\tSeat number: {seat}")


# Empty dictionary to store info later on.
user_tickets = {}

# List of seats the user can choose from.
available_seats = ['1a', '2a', '19b', '20d', '21e', '13g', '15f', '14f', '13a', '12g' ]


# All prompts.
start_prompt = "\nWould you like to start booking your ticket? (yes/no) "
wanted_seats_prompt = "\nHow many seats are you booking today?"
wanted_seats_prompt += "\nEnter the number: "
name_prompt = "What is your name? "
seat_prompt = "\nPlease enter the number of the seat you would like to book: "
go_again_prompt = "Would you like to let someone else book their tickets? (yes/no) "


print("Welcome To The Seat Booking Portal!")

# Ask the user if he would like to start booking their tickets.
start = input(start_prompt)
if start.lower() == 'yes':
    # Runs until it reaches a break statement.
    while True:
        # Empty list to store the seat(s) the user has chosen.
        seats = []

        # Find out how many times to run the while loop.
        wanted_seats = input(wanted_seats_prompt)
        # Convert the string representation of the number to an integer representation.
        wanted_seats = int(wanted_seats)
        # If the user has asked for more seats than the number of seats
        # available execute this block.
        if wanted_seats > len(available_seats):
            print(f"\n--I'm sorry, we only have {len(available_seats)} "
                "seats available--")
            print("--Please try again--")
            continue

        # Ask for the users name.
        user_name = input(name_prompt)

        # Run until the user has chosen the requested number of seats.
        while True:

            # Show the user the available seats.
            print("\nHere are the available seats:")
            for seat in available_seats:
                print(seat)

            # Ask the user for their chosen seat number.
            seat = input(seat_prompt)

            # If the user has entered a seat that is in the 'available_seats' 
            # list; remove it from the 'available_seats' list.
            if seat in available_seats:
                available_seats.remove(seat)
            # The user has entered a seat that is not in the 'avialbe_seats' list.
            # Ask for their seat again.
            else:
                print("\n--I'm sorry you have chosen an invalid seat--"
                    "\n-Please try again-")
                continue

            # Add the chosen seat to the 'seats' list
            seats.append(seat)

            # If the user has said that they are going to book more than one seat
            # go through this seat booking 'while' loop again.
            if wanted_seats > 1:
                print("\nYou can now choose another seat.")
                # The loop will run a limited number of times.
                # It will only 'continue' when there is more than one 'wanted_seat'.
                wanted_seats-=1
                continue
            else:
                break

        # Add the 'user_name' variable and 'seats' list to the 'user_tickets' dictionary.
        user_tickets[user_name] = seats

        #If their are any available seats left ask the user if he
        # wants to let another person book their tickets. 
        if available_seats:
            go_again = input(go_again_prompt)
            if go_again == 'no':
                break
        else:
            break

    print_tickets()
    print("\nWe will now redirect you to the payment portal."
        "\nThank You for choosing us.")

else:
    print("You can always come by later!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are aware more or less of this (given your PS), but comments have to be there just when they are useful. Some of them that you should remove:

```
# Empty dictionary to store info later on.
# List of seats the user can choose from.
# All prompts.
# Runs until it reaches a break statement.
# Find out how many times to run the while loop.
# Convert the string representation of the number to an integer representation.
# If the user has asked for more seats than the number of seats
        # available execute this block.
# Ask for the users name.
```

And you get the idea. Comments don't have to be redundant with the code, and they don't explain always what the code does, but they explain something that is not obvious reading the code. Also, in this case, they make more difficult reading the script, given the extension of them.

Also, do you even need a function at all? It is only used once, so unless you are going to extend the code in the future, you could just place those lines of code where the call of the function is.

Instead of having several prints in a row, you could use triple quote string, as follows:

```
print(f"""\n--I'm sorry, we only have {len(available_seats)} 
                seats available--
                --Please try again--""")
```